# How can a Ukrainian refugee be evicted? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, eviction

A close family member has offered to provide housing for a refugee.
This was arranged via the council (in other words, the refugee's previous sponsor had been unwilling to continue to host them).

For various reasons, including low grade identity theft, my family member wants the refugee to leave their house ASAP.

The council has previously indicated that the way to go about doing this would be to take the refugee to a hotel and to contact the council, at which point they will take over as the person will be homeless.

I'm concerned that, given the circumstances, the refugee may be unwilling to leave the house. I'm also concerned for my family member's safety.

Is there a legal (and safe) avenue for them to enact/enforce their decision?

Comment: I am sorry but we are not a legal clinic and can't give you legal advice. [Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer). Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

Comment: Perhaps you can contact [Shelter England](https://england.shelter.org.uk/). Although they are pro-tenant, they have pages relating to accomodation obtained by refugees and asylum seekers, although it is focused on UKVI not Council re-housing. Such as [Housing for refugees and people fleeing war](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/homelessness/housing_for_refugees) which has information about Ukraine. This and other pages might not answer the question, but they do give some background.

Comment: ...  Also [The categories of excluded occupiers who can be lawfully evicted without the landlord obtaining a possession order](https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/renting/occupiers_with_limited_security/excluded_occupiers).

Comment: Just curious, what is "low grade identity theft"?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, and apologies if the question is inappropriate (I'd have thought it is a topic that would have reasonably broad interest atm though!).

Comment: @MichaelHall social media accounts with their name and address have suddenly popped up contacting local people asking for small favours. I'm not quite sure what the end goal is but it smells like a scam. It may not be the refugee themselves but various patterns make it very clear that it is either them or an associate.